# Python Tornado Swagger: only one usage of each socket address

Tags: python, error-handling, swagger, tornado

I run my proyect on PyCharm last version.
When I run my main.py it runs good and behaivor is desired. But If I restart (or re-run) the main.py, I got error

`OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

No other isntances running. Python is the only thing on computer now. No other usages of ports. The only way to skip this error is or restarting computer or deleting every python from task manager.

**Also, after stopping service, Swagger is still accesible with browser**, I think that this swagger is using the port for main (because they run together) and that is why I can't run my main.py.

One way to reproduce this error is run this MWE, then stop and close PyCharm or just close Pycharm, then try to restart it and the message error comes again, and swagger is still up!. This happen while I'm coding and try to run the new things I wrote.

**MWE:**

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado_swagger.setup import setup_swagger
from tornado.options import parse_command_line,define,options
from tornado.web import Application,url,RequestHandler
class TestRequests(RequestHandler):
    def get(self,var1):
        """
        ---
        tags:
        - Testing
        summary: minimal working example
        description: some dummy text
        produces:
        - requestsBody:
        - application/json
        parameters:
        -   name: var1
            in: path
            description: dummy tet
            required: true
            type: string
        responses:
            200:
              description: dummy response for dummy requests here and now
        """
        print(f"Reveived GET tests for {var1}")
        res = {"result": "hello",
               "product": str(var1)+"-foo"}
        self.write(res)
class Applications(Application):
    urls = [
        url(r"/api/(?P<var1>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/test",TestRequests)
           ]
    def __init__(self):
        settings = {'debug': True}
        setup_swagger(self.urls,
                      swagger_url = '/swagger',
                      api_base_url="/Base",
                      description = "test swagger",
                      title = "test title")
        super(Applications,self).__init__(self.urls,**settings)
define('port', default='8088', help='Port to listen on')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("running")
    parse_command_line()
    app = Applications()
    app.listen(options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Server Client program error: "OSError: \[WinError 10048\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596009/python-server-client-program-error-oserror-winerror-10048)

Comment: No. It is not the same problem.